# Libhand library compilation error

Tags: 14.04

I'm trying to build a hand model library from libhand.org on Ubuntu 14.04. The library uses ogre and opencv libraries. I followed the instructions provided by the author that allowed me to successfully install ogre and opencv. There is no problem with cmake .. . but during execute command

```
make -j4
```

I get the following error:

```
[ 87%] Building CXX object source/CMakeFiles/hand_renderer.dir/hand_pose.cc.o
[ 91%] Building CXX object source/CMakeFiles/hand_renderer.dir/scene_spec.cc.o
Linking CXX static library libhand_renderer.a
[ 91%] Built target hand_renderer
Scanning dependencies of target pose_designer
[ 95%] Building CXX object source/CMakeFiles/pose_designer.dir/pose_designer_main.cc.o
[100%] Building CXX object source/CMakeFiles/pose_designer.dir/pose_designer.cc.o
Linking CXX executable pose_designer
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lNOTFOUND
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lNOTFOUND
libhand_utils.a(file_dialog.cc.o): In function `libhand::FileDialog::TkExec(std::string const&)':
file_dialog.cc:(.text+0xead): warning: the use of `mktemp' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp' or `mkdtemp'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [source/pose_designer] Error 1
make[1]: *** [source/CMakeFiles/pose_designer.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Does anyone know why this error occurs and what can be done?

Comment: Looks like an error in the Makefile, I've never seen a library with the name `NOTFOUND`

Answer (score 2):

if you're still interested in an answer, in the months since you posted this question in November 2015, I have started being the maintainer of the most popular version of LibHand that was uploaded to GitHub.

We have moved the repository to https://github.com/libhand/libhand/

As of writing LibHand should compilation and run fine on modern Debian (and derivatives such as Ubuntu) if you follow those instructions.

> #### Satisfying software dependencies under Debian/Ubuntu
>
> The following instructions allow compilation of LibHand without too much trouble on all versions of Debian/Ubuntu currently supported by the Debian Project and Canonical.
>
> See the 'Supported platform' section of README.md for exact OS versions LibHand currently supports.
>
> ```sh
> sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake git libogre-1.9-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libxt-dev libopencv-dev tcl tk libboost-system-dev libboost-filesystem-dev
> ```
>
> On Ubuntu 12.04 and Debian Wheezy, there is no libogre-1.9-dev package available, so substitute with libogre-dev (which is v1.7.4 on those systems).
>
> On a fresh Ubuntu 12.04/14.04/16.04 install, if apt-get is unable to locate the OpenCV (libopencv-dev) and OGRE packages, append 'universe' to your sources.list, run sudo apt-get update and try again.
>
> #### Compiling libhand and pose_designer
>
> ```sh
> git clone https://github.com/libhand/libhand
> mkdir build
> cd build
> cmake ..
> make
> # Collate libhand build artifacts into local "dist" directory (for external applications to link against)
> make install
> # Ensure path exists first: on 32-bit, x86_64 is replaced with i386. Replace OGRE version with whatever was installed (likely OGRE-1.9.0, OGRE-1.8.0, or OGRE-1.7.4).
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/OGRE-1.9.0
> ./hand_cpp/source/pose_designer
> ```

([Source](https://github.com/libhand/libhand/blob/master/docs/build_instructions/debian/BUILD.DEBIAN.md))

Comment: Appreciate your effort in maintaining the software. To prevent this answer from being flagged/deleted as a link-only answer, can you please provide compilation/installation instructions in your answer?